App not installing INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS Error
I just bought a new tablet the Oneplus Pad 2 (Android 14) and when I try to install an apk of app that I use it gives me the error
App not installed as the app isn't compatible with your tablet

This same APK I'm able to install this on my Xiaomi pad 6 (running Android 14) which has a snapdragon 870 and this Oneplus pad has a Snapdragon 8 gen 3
I tried to install via adb, which gave me this error
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

Help me please, how do I fix this? I have read that this is because some libraries are missing, I don't know what that means.
Note: My Oneplus pad and Xiaomi pad are both rooted

From the error messages and processor types it is quite clear what your problem is. The app uses native code libraries. The APK you're trying to install only has 32-bit versions of the libraries. The Snapdragon 8 Gen 3 has no cores that can run 32-bit code. It is only capable of running 64-bit native code.
The Snapdragon 870, while an older and slower design, can run 32-bit native code and so can run this APK.
You need an version of the APK that provides 64-bit native code libraries. Those are the missing libraries you've heard about. The Play store has that, since the app works if you install it from there.

Firstly, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. But, the problem is that when I'm installing the app from playstore it works just fine, the apk I have is also the same version. How is it that when I'm trying install the same version apk it says not compatible.

@RohithRathod nowadays, APKs are bundled to specific device configuration (including native libraries based on the CPU architecture) to reduce size. Play Store will always deliver the correct bundle, but if you extract the APK manually, then you might not have the correct bundle for other devices.

Okay thank you for the clarification, so I just have to see if anyone uploads the apk that is compatible with my new tablet.

@RohithRathod: Thanks for the clarifications, updated the answer.
